My account and my questions have been deleted
So I log in today and I see that my account has been deleted. I have 0 question 0 answers. I asked a question yesterday and that has been deleted too. Anyone care to explain? I had three question on my account as far as I can remember, one with 12 upvotes, the other with 7 upvotes
Here are the questions 
Can social media be applied to algorithmic trading?
How to combine multiple trading algorithms?
This is the question I asked yesterday https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/2394/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-implementing-a-day-trading-algorithm-in-java-or-c/2397#2397
In addition, I'm writing a research paper on algorithmic trading this year and I had about 30 questions favorited in my account that I have to reference in my paper as they had very useful link. And now those are gone too!!! 
What's more, I have to write a preliminary report by tomorrow and I need the links to my favorites, it took me several days to research all those questions!

Your main user's content has been restored.

@JarrodDixon Thanks. Josh emailed me as well that you guys were on the case.

Your favorites have been restored, as well; good luck on your paper!

@JarrodDixon Thanks a lot!

I deleted your account. You asked a Java-vs-C++ question. This site has been through its share of programming-language holy wars and I wasn't going to allow that again.
You also asked for people to help you pirate a text book. That "question" got closed and heavily down-voted, though you never deleted it.
It's also worth pointing out that your first question from a few weeks ago was on what skills were required to enter HFT. From the FAQ, this site is intended for people involved in quantitative finance as a career. That isn't you.
Anyone is welcome to read this site. But there is a minimum skill level required for posting, as many of the early discussions on Meta have worked out.
You've had three out of five questions closed, two of which needed to be deleted. Perhaps I jumped the gun; perhaps I should have just suspended your account and manually deleted those questions. But I do have a tolerance limit when it comes to people from outside the industry who repeatedly post beginner questions. And I wasn't going to wait for you to ask where you could find free data online.

Most people on this site have a PhD; your educational background won't impress anybody. And your two questions are not "very high quality". The reason I didn't want you asking about data online is that it's the most overplayed question on here [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ].

@chrisaycock You deleted an active account because the user post three bad questions and doesn't have a PhD? I'd have been surprised if you suspended for something as minor as three questions; you can just comment on them and delete the individual posts

@bizso09 Richardh and I dug around to see what's possible. We can't find an undelete option, nor can we view your previous account. However, you can try contacting team@stackoverflow.com to see if they can help.

Looking into it - gimme a few.

I've read that answer, don't worry about it. The poster recommended using Grails for webdev.
